# Bigfoot - problem in automatically or manually perform line breaks

Tags: line-breaking, footnotes, bigfoot

I am using the bigfoot package in order to have two categories of footnotes along with the parameter `para`, in order to place the footnotes one after the other. The problem I am facing is on the line breaking of a single footnote. Though the package automatically places a new footnote on the next line when there is no space left, it doesn't do the same for one single footnote and no matter how long it is it keeps it on same line.

Is there a way of doing this splitting automatically for single footnotes? I have tried to do it manually using `\\`, and I still faced trouble because the successor footnotes of the one which had the line break were also automatically placed in a new line and not the same according to `para`. Here is a sample of my code:

Edit: Sorry, you are perfectly right about the fake long word. The only problem is actually when I want to manually break the line or move the next footnotes below. Then I get an unwanted extra line break after the next footnote.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[ruled, para]{bigfoot}
\newfootnote[para]{A}
\newfootnote[para]{B}

\begin{document}
This is a text\FootnotetextA{}{First footnote} \FootnotetextA{}{Second footnote} \FootnotetextA{}{etc} \FootnotetextA{}{etc} \FootnotetextA{}{etcaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
\FootnotetextA{}{etc} \FootnotetextA{}{etc} \FootnotetextA{}{etc \\} 
\FootnotetextA{}{etc} \FootnotetextA{}{etc} \FootnotetextA{}{etc}

\FootnotetextB{}{This is the second footnote} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't that a problem of TeX not knowing where it can break the fake long word..?  Add a `\-` in your 'etcaaaaaa<etc.>`.

Comment: or else add \\ in the middle of the long word

Comment: Hmm, odd behaviour indeed.  A quick work around would be to define something like `\newcommand{\fnbreak}{\vspace*{0.01ex}}` and then use `\fnbreak` instead of `\par` or whatever.

Comment: This also happens with `fnpara` and `footmisx`.

Answer (score 2):

There must be some sort of bug in `bigfoot`. If you don't mind to use `manyfoot`, instead, it works fine:

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[ruled, para]{manyfoot}
\newfootnote[para]{A}
\newfootnote[para]{B}

\begin{document}
This is a text\FootnotetextA{}{First footnote} \FootnotetextA{}{Second footnote} 
\FootnotetextA{}{etc} \FootnotetextA{}{etc}
\FootnotetextA{}{etc} \FootnotetextA{}{etc} \FootnotetextA{}{etc\\}
\FootnotetextA{}{etc} \FootnotetextA{}{etc} \FootnotetextA{}{etc}

\FootnotetextB{}{This is the second footnote}

\end{document}
```

[image]